# Arxiv after acceptance

Tags: publications, ethics, copyright

I had submitted a paper, say X-1, on a reputed Springer (Birkhauser) journal of our field. After two major revisions I received an Ad hoc email from the editor which says that the paper is accepted, however the journal can only sent the formal acceptance mail on coming months (March 2022) due to the excessive congestion of articles.

Now, I have completed a follow up article, say X-2, based on X-1, which is ready to be submitted. Since I have cited X-1 in X-2, I need to make it available for the referee and reviewers of the journal where I am planning to submit X-2. Can I put X-1 in arxiv now? At least the primary version, where the revisions was not incorporated?

I read the publication ethics but that does not address my query. For reference https://www.springer.com/gp/editorial-policies/ethical-responsibilities-of-authors

Comment: What do the submission guidelines of the journal for X-1 say?

Comment: I checked it after your comment and found several points. It says it will follow the COPE guidelines under the section "Ethical Responsibilities of Authors". The submission guidelines are similar to that of most other Springer Journals. Thank you @GoodDeeds

Comment: Ask the editor that sent you the letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most journals will not explicitly prevent you from putting a revised version of X-1 on a web page of your choice (including arxiv.org) *provided* it meets some conditions. For example, you need to use a "generic" style (like article style) rather than the journal's style file which may be copyrighted.
2. It may be possible for the journal which accepted X-1 to give you a unique journal-based identifier for it so that you can use it in your references. It would then be possible for you to use that reference in X-2. The journal will probably be happy to do this as it improves their citation rates.
3. Note that the editor/referee of your paper *does* have access to the arXiv, so they will be able to access X-1 in its most recent form if you follow (1).